# What is the maximum file size you can download through the marketplace over a cell connection?

Tags: android, download

What is the maximum file size you can download through the marketplace over a cell connection.

For example, on the iphone the maximum size is 20MB, if the content is over 20MB then you must connected via wifi or itunes.

Does this limit exist for andriod?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked there was no limit other than the 50 MB apk filesize. However, this could be carrier enforced/specific.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no hard limit, but there's a finite amount of battery that will be drained pretty quickly with that kind of sustained DL.

See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUemfrKe65c

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a hard fact but I noticed [World of Goo Demo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.twodboy.worldofgoodemo&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLnR3b2Rib3kud29ybGRvZmdvb2RlbW8iXQ..) is Wifi only, and it is 27.94MB according to the Market. It is the only Wifi only app that I have seen on the Market (but there are quite a few on Amazon appstore).

On the other hand, Skype is 10.02MB and it is not Wifi only. So if I had to guess I would go with ~25MB is the threshold.